# Return a value to Html Control from CGI

Tags: c++, textbox, cgi, return-value

I have written CGI program Using c++ to add two numbers. I gave input two numbers in two text fields and passed the data to CGI program and added it. I showed the result in new web page as plain text . But i want to show the result in another text field of the same webpage  which i received input . Or I want to show the answer in the different HTML page Text Field. How can i do this ?

Comment: You need to send across the HTML file as the response (read the file and send across the contents). if you want in a textbox value, set appropriate HTML before sending it.

Comment: I already designed a html which having a only one text box control. I need to set result of that addition in that text box value. Is there any sample code available ?

Comment: Sorry to say, but this place is not for "sample code". Show us your effort at doing it, tell us where you are stuck and we will be glad to help you..

Comment: I want to "send data from CGI program to Text Field". I searched in lot sites. There is only available send data to CGI program with the text field .